# Specific Question About Open/Close Sets.

Tags: general-topology

So I had a question about open/close subsets because we started this in Topology today.

So let's take an closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so, for example $X = [-2, 2]$.

Let's say I want to compare if a set is closed in $X$ vs a set closed in $\mathbb{R}$ what would be the main difference?

So let's say I have 3 sets, say $Y_1 = \{x\ | 1 < x < 2 \}$, $Y_2 = \{x\ | 1 \leq x < 2 \}$, $Y_3 = \{x\ | 1 < x \leq 2 \}$.

Like looking at $Y_1$ this set is open in $X$ because $1$ and $2$ are limit points of the set and they're not contained in $Y_1$ and similarly to $\mathbb{R}$.

So for $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ would these not be open in $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$? Is there a difference between comparing closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such as $X$ vs $\mathbb{R}$ given the sets I have defined?

Comment: $Y_3$ is open because the complementary is $[-2,1]$ which is close. For $Y_2$ is neither open nor close.

Answer (score 1):

$Y_1$ is indeed open, in both $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$, but not for the reason you say. It's open, because every point is an interior point, or you could look at the complement, which in $\mathbb{R}$ is $(-\infty,1] \cup [2, \infty)$, which is indeed closed (it contains all its limit points). But openness is more direct, as $Y_1$ is an open interval which is open by definition (if you use the order topology definition) or an open ball (around $1\frac{1}{2}$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$) if you use the metric definition, so directly open in $\mathbb{R}$.

If $A \subset X \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is also open in $X$. In general, $A$ is open in $X$ iff there exists some $A'$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A' \cap X = A$. Here we can use $A' = A$, e.g. for $Y_1$.

The same holds for closed sets as well.

But a set can be open in $X$ without being open in $\mathbb{R}$, and $Y_3$ is an example of that. We can take for $A = Y_3$ the set $A' = \{1 < x < 3 \}$, which is open in the reals (open interval etc.) and $A' \cap X = A$. But $Y_3$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$, as $2$ is not an interior point of $Y_3$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (but it is an interior point in $X$!).

The set $Y_2$ is neither open in $\mathbb{R}$ not in $X$, now failing both at $x=1$ to be an interior point.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes a lot more sense. Though I'm kind of confused at why it matters to intersect $A'$ and $X$ to showing it's an open set. I can see why it's an open set from one of the comments.

Comment: @Andy It's a theorem that an open set in a subspace is the intersection of an open set in the large space, intersected with that subspace. This coincides with taking relative metrics, e.g.

Comment: Ah okay. Last question! Why is $x = 2$ an interior point of $Y_3$ in $X$? Isn't the definition of an interior point the points in the interior excluding the boundary? So isn't $x=2$ a boundary point?

Comment: Look at the metric view: the ball in $X$ around $x=2$ with radius $1$ is by definition the set of all points of $X$ (not of the reals!) that have distance $<1$ to $2$, and this is exactly $Y_3$. So $2$ is the centre of the ball even, so an interior point. The points outside of $X$ do not count in the subspace topology.

Answer (score 0):

Because $X$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ all closed subsets of $X$ are also closed in $\mathbb R$.

*Proof:* Take $A \subseteq X$ close. Thus $X\setminus A$ is open. Also $\mathbb R\setminus X$ is open because $X$ is close in $\mathbb R$. So $\mathbb R \setminus A = (\mathbb R\setminus X) \cup (X\setminus A)$ is open which proves that $A$ is close in $\mathbb R$.

The same is not true, if $X$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$. Take for example $\tilde X = ]-2,2[$. Regarding to $\tilde X$ the set $Y_2 = \{x|1\le x<2\}$ is closed but $Y_2$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$.

Note: Not all open subsets of $X$ are open in $\mathbb R$ as you can see in the comments...

Comment: Sorry but is $\tilde X = (-2 , 2)$?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, $]-2,2[$ is another notation for $(-2,2)$... :-)